# When does a memory dump get written after BSOD?

Tags: bsod, windows-xp-embedded

I have a machine that periodically BSOD's.  I have full memory dumps configured.  Sometimes, when rebooting AFTER the BSOD, the machine sits on a black screen for several minutes, then finally comes up to windows.  My colleague just recently found out that during this time, the machine was writing the full memory dump to disk.

He identified this by shutting the machine down on the BSOD, plugging the drive in as a slave, seeing that no dump file was present, plugging it back into a machine, seeing the black screen for several minutes, and then finding the memory dump on disk.

So my question is, how does this work, internally?  I swear I've seen the BSOD itself telling me that it is currently writing the dump file to disk, with a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the BSOD overwrites the pagefile with the full contents of memory in order to avoid doing any complicated processing after a critical system error (bear in mind that the cause of the BSOD could have damaged any heaps, code, unloaded drivers etc, so the BSOD basically can't rely on anything). When the system reboots it discovers that the pagefile's been marked as a BSOD, and then sets about converting the RAW dump to a minidump file that can be analysed either by Microsoft's crash-reporting server or by a driver developer analysing the crash dump in WinDbg or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know for sure, its possible that it has to write RAM to disk while displaying the screen, but when it reboots, it pulls the rest of the process memory space out of the swap file to create the full core dump.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable explanation.  Hopefully someone can bring some documentation, Google has failed me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I hear something like that. I though the dump was always writting while the BSOD is shown. You can try to connect the kernel debugger in verbose mode and figure out what's happening.